# Easy way to replace Data with ComboBox? Or populate ComboBox from Data

Tags: data-binding, vb6, combobox

I took over a very old project written in VB6, it's a mess and I don't really know VB so it would be great if someone could help me.

I have a *Data* control which gets records from an Access database which I would like to replace with some kind of drop down list - I thought about *ComboBox*. Unfortunately I cannot get records from the database in the same way as with *Data*, so I thought about populating *ComboBox* based on what's in the *Data* control. How can I achieve it? Or is there a better way to do it?

My last resort is to create all database methods manually in order to replicate *Data*'s behaviour for *ComboBox* but I think it's too much effort for such a small change.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Data control does more than just let them browse through the records, it manages the database, current record, data binding, etc.
The easiest way to do what you want is to hide/move the data control and use its `.Recordset.Find*()` methods.
Note that DAO is archaic and has been supersceded at least once for VB6 (with ADO)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Yeah, that's exactly the problem with the _Data_ control. I didn't really know about `find` - thanks! I'll try it tomorrow at work and will report here.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to my post. Thanks